# Ingenico 6550 won't display signature box

Tags: c#, forms, capture, signature

I'd call Ingenico's tech support, but I don't have a month to wait for their callback.

Our app uses the 6550 and it displays all the forms just fine except, on one machine it's not showing the signature box on the signature capture form. It shows the buttons and text just fine.

I've tried using our app, I've tried the Ingenico test app. Everything seems to check out fine. The only thing I get in th log is this:

**2/17/2011 8:43:33 AM (31813 ms)** EC0000  Device name [Ing6XXX] - UPOS-Interface-App error code=0xFD

It's followed by these lines after I dismiss the form:

**2/17/2011 8:43:33 AM (31860 ms**) EC0000  Device name [Ing6XXX] - Last platform error code from device=0x2, desc=SingleButtonEntry: ssaSecFuncKe
**2/17/2011 8:43:33 AM (31860 ms**) EC0111  Device name [Ing6XXX] - SIG - Direct IO - Command 12 - Invalid command, or function code missing. Length 5 [Package {00 05 95 FD 6D}] [Translation {iDataLength 0}{ucFunctionCode 95}{ucResponseCode FD}{ucResultCode 6D}{sData }]
**2/17/2011 8:43:33 AM (31860 ms)** EC0111  Device name [Ing6XXX] - SO APP - Direct IO - Command 12 - Invalid command, or function code missing. Length 5 [Package {00 05 95 FD 6D}] [Translation {iDataLength 0}{ucFunctionCode 95}{ucResponseCode FD}{ucResultCode 6D}{sData }]

I'm not sure if that's related. Does anyone have experience with these things. Any idea what might cause the failure to display the signature box?

Comment: no experience at all, but it looks like you're trying to call a function on the device that doesn't exist.  I'd suggest double-checking the version of the device hardware/bios(?) and the version you're building your application against.

Comment: Yes, that was my interpretation of those message as well, except I have confirmed that there is only one build of the DLLs and OCXs on the machine and that those match the only version on the development machine. Those errors, I don't believe, are involved in the actual display of the form, but with the cleanup afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a missing registry setting for the form location. Not sure how we missed that.